# Angular 6 select input testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with testing the select control in angular 6 and I am probably missing something obvious.

I have such a select control.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-light form-control-sm w-25 m-1" aria-label="Recent" [(ngModel)]="_selectedTenant">
<option *ngFor="let tenant of _tenants" [ngValue]="tenant.value">{{tenant.name}}</option>
```

It binds to pretty simple component.

```
export class TopNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

 _currentLang: string;
 _tenants: Tenant[];
 _selectedTenant: string;

 constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private tenantService: TenantService) {
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this._currentLang = this.translate.currentLang;

this.tenantService.getTenants().subscribe(
  (tenants) => {
    this._tenants = tenants
    this._selectedTenant = this._tenants[0].value;
  },
  (error) => console.error(error)
)}}
```

And my test class with this one failing test

```
describe('TopNavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: TopNavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TopNavbarComponent>;

  let translateService: TranslateService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: JsonTranslationLoader }
      })],
      declarations: [TopNavbarComponent],
      providers: [TranslateService]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    translateService = TestBed.get(TranslateService);

    translateService.currentLang = 'en';

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TopNavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should init after ngOnInit observables completes', fakeAsync(() => {
    const topnavElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const selectElement = topnavElement.querySelector('select');

    expect(selectElement.value).toEqual('');

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component._tenants).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component._tenants.length).toEqual(2);
    expect(component._selectedTenant).toEqual(component._tenants[0].value);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    console.log(selectElement);
    expect(selectElement.value).toEqual(component._selectedTenant);
  }));
```

And yet last expect fails. Select value is never there, it always appears as ''. I tried attribute selectedOptions but its length is 0.

I am unable to get this one value that supposed to be selected after setting _selectedTenant up in onInit that is bound to select with ngModel.

I now that this question is probably trivial but I never found an answer anywhere why this might be happening.

I am sure I will feel stupid after someone resolves this in like 1 minute after posting :(

Nevertheless, thanks foryour help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, here's what worked for me:

```
expect(selectElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-model')).toEqual(component._selectedTenant);
```

Comment: This works however the attribute name right now is ng-reflect-model. Maybe it changed in one of angular versions?

Answer (score 0):

While testing `dom` contents and values, you should fetch the `dom` elements every time when your view gets updated (i.e after doing `fixture.detectChanges()`)

Add these two lines after `fixture.detectChanges()`

```
topnavElement = fixture.nativeElement;
selectElement = topnavElement.querySelector('select');
```

And use `let` instead of `const`, because you will be modifying those variables.

full spec

```
it('should init after ngOnInit observables completes', fakeAsync(() => {
    let topnavElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    let selectElement = topnavElement.querySelector('select');

    expect(selectElement.value).toEqual('');

    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component._tenants).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component._tenants.length).toEqual(2);
    expect(component._selectedTenant).toEqual(component._tenants[0].value);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // fetch dom elements again to get updated data
    topnavElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    selectElement = topnavElement.querySelector('select');

    console.log(selectElement);
    expect(selectElement.value).toEqual(component._selectedTenant);
  }));
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is exactly the same :( I kind of like this answer because it is a logical explanation but it does not work in this scenario. Value is still empty. Nicolas.leblanc's answer solves problem although the name of the attribute was changed to ng-reflect-model

Comment: Yes that should definitely work. Not sure if `querySelector` being the problem. Can you try `selectElement = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('select'));`
and then `expect(selectElement.nativeElement.value).toEqual(component._selectedTenant);`

Comment: Sorry it has to be `query()` not `queryAll()`.

Comment: Sorry still the same. Expected '' to be '1'